# Combine Multiple Pandas DataFrames Via Index

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am going cross eyed on this and hopefully someone can answer the question for me. I have a list of DataFrames with only a timestamp as an index and a column for sales (depending on state). What I am trying to do is combine all the DataFrames in the list and output a new one. Example Dataframes would appear:

```
    |   time    | USA |   
    |-----------|-----|   
    | 12-1-2012 |   1 |   
    | 12-2-2012 |   1 | 
    | 12-3-2012 |   1 |  
    | 12-4-2012 |   3 |   
    | 12-5-2012 |   5 |   
    | 12-6-2012 |   6 |   
    | 12-7-2012 |   4 |   
    | 12-8-2012 |   2 |   
    | 12-9-2012 |   5 |   


    |   time    | UK  |
    |-----------|-----|
    | 12-1-2012 |   1 |
    | 12-2-2012 |   1 |
    | 12-5-2012 |   5 |
    | 12-6-2012 |   6 |
    | 12-7-2012 |   4 |
    | 12-8-2012 |   2 |
    | 12-9-2012 |   5 |


    |   time    | CAN |
    |-----------|-----|
    | 12-1-2012 |   1 |
    | 12-2-2012 |   1 |
    | 12-4-2012 |   3 |
    | 12-6-2012 |   4 |
    | 12-8-2012 |   2 |
    | 12-9-2012 |   5 |


    |   time    | USA | UK  | CAN |   
    |-----------|-----|-----|-----|   
    | 12-1-2012 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   
    | 12-2-2012 |   1 |   1 |   1 |
    | 12-3-2012 |   1 | NaN | NaN |    
    | 12-4-2012 |   3 | NaN | NaN |   
    | 12-5-2012 |   5 |   5 | NaN |   
    | 12-6-2012 |   6 |   6 |   6 |   
    | 12-7-2012 |   4 |   4 |   4 |   
    | 12-8-2012 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   
    | 12-9-2012 |   5 |   5 |   5 |
```

The last table is technically what I want to happen. I want all of them to be combined on the time and if it doesn't have that key then just add a `NaN` value for now. I am running into some oddities. The frames are stored in a list:

```
    dataframes = [d1,d2,d3]
```

What I have tried is to use a reduce method while joining and it seems to mangle the data. Here is a full example.

```
    d1 = ts.copy()
    d1.columns = ['time']
    d1.index = d1['time']
    # del d1['time']
    d1['USA'] = range(9)

    d2 = ts.copy()
    d2.columns = ['time']
    d2.index = d2['time']
    # del d2['time']
    d2['UK'] = range(9)

    d3 = ts.copy()
    d3.columns = ['time']
    d3.index = d3['time']
    # del d3['time']
    d3['UK'] = range(9)

    d2.drop(d2.index[[2,3]])
    d3.drop(d3.index[[2,4,6]])

    dataframes = [d1, d2, d3]

    df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='time'), dataframes)
    df_final

    # Output

    time    USA         UK_x    UK_y
    0       2012-12-01  0       0   0
    1       2012-12-02  1       1   1
    2       2012-12-03  2       2   2
    3       2012-12-04  3       3   3
    4       2012-12-05  4       4   4
    5       2012-12-06  5       5   5
    6       2012-12-07  6       6   6
    7       2012-12-08  7       7   7
    8       2012-12-09  8       8   8
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction without telling me to read the documentation.

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Comment: `pd.concat([df.set_index('time') for df in dfs], axis=1)`  where `dfs` is the list holding your DataFrames.

Comment: If `time` is the index, just use concat. `pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)`

Comment: What fields? It works on your example DataFrames https://imgur.com/a/5SvEO

Comment: It works. Issue was 'inplace' was not in the drop.